# How to highlight text based on regions--not regular expresions

Tags: font-lock, highlighting

When font-lock-mode is enabled I cannot get custom faces to stick with add-text-properties or set-text-properties. I've looked through libraries like hi-lock.el, but they all seem to be regexp based. I want to highlight by points; (point) to (point-max) for example.

How can I highlight text (similar to hi-lock) by regions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can get highlighting to "stick" by using property `font-lock-face` instead of property `face`.

Second, you can do what you want (using either property) with library [**`highlight.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary).

You can use command **`hlt-highlight`** to highlight or unhighlight
the region, or to highlight or unhighlight a regexp throughout the
region, depending on the prefix argument.  It combines the
behaviors of commands `hlt-highlight-region`,
`hlt-unhighlight-region`, `hlt-highlight-regexp-region`, and
`hlt-highlight-regexp-region`.